# Avoid locking the screen while ProgressDialog is displaying

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to show a progressBar while some instructions execute in background, but I don't want to lock the screen. This code is locking the screen:

```
private class ConvertDataInBackground extends AsyncTask<Params, Void, Boolean> {

        private MyProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            if(mProgressDialog == null)
                mProgressDialog = MyProgressDialog.show(mActivity, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Params...params) {
            boolean conversionResult = executeConversion(params[0].item1, params[0].item2, params[0].item3);
            return conversionResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            try {
                if(mProgressDialog.isShowing()) 
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if(result) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mActivity, R.string.conversion_result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Execution of instruction in background may take a while, and I want the user to be able to work with the interface.
Do you know anyway that we can work with interface, while progressDialog is displaying at the top?

Comment: Dialogs in Android are usually modal.  You can try creating the dialog then adding `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` to its window parameters - but I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Thanks @AleksG. You can share your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Take a look at the `PowerManager` API and the `WakeLock` method. There's various flags you can call to prevent dimming, locking and sleeping. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dialogs in Android are usually modal. You can try creating the dialog then adding FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL to its window parameters - but I'm not sure if it will work.  The idea behind it will be something like this:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setMessage(...);
dialog.setTitle(...);
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Note at the same time that it may be easier to just add a `ProgressBar` to your activity's layout and show it when needed instead of creating a dialog - this is, in fact, what Google documentation recommends.  [Android developer's guide on dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) has this to say:

> **Avoid ProgressDialog**
>
> Android includes another dialog class called `ProgressDialog` that shows
>   a dialog with a progress bar. However, if you need to indicate loading
>   or indeterminate progress, you should instead follow the design
>   guidelines for `Progress & Activity` and use a `ProgressBar` in your
>   layout.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your activity you must specify the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

For me it worked.